# My workflow template in GCP consists of 2 jobs A & B ( B runs after A ). How do I ensure B runs even if job A fails?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have observed that job B runs only if job A is successful. But I want job B to run even if job A fails.

Need in the same sequence job B after job A. Used --start-after to achieve this

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark <> --region=us-west1 --step-id=A --workflow-template=WF1 

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark <> --region=us-west1 --step-id=B --start-after=A --workflow-template=WF1
```

Comment: It does not seem possible to control the status and to react to success or failure.